# Integration of product of functions of "x" with exponents/powers (binomial problem)

Tags: probability, binomial-distribution, integral

Original problem:  A point X is randomly chosen from the interval (0,1).  Suppose ***X=x*** is observed.  Then a coin with ***P(Heads) = x*** is tossed independently ***n*** times.  Let ***Y*** be the number of heads in ***n*** tosses.  Find the unconditional distribution of ***Y***.

I've setup the problem below using total probability and a uniform pdf of ***x*** (a confirmation others agree my formulation is correct would be nice), but not sure how to integrate this:

$\int_{0}^{1}$$\begin{pmatrix}n\\y\end{pmatrix}$$x^y(1-x)^{n-y}\,dx$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To approach this, I would apply the [binomial theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem), which holds for non-negative integer $c$:

$$
(a+b)^c = \sum_{i=0}^c {c\choose i} a^ib^{c-i}
$$

When you apply this identity to $(1-x)^{n-y}$, the integrand becomes a standard polynomial in $x$:

\begin{align*}
Pr(Y=y) &= {n\choose y}\int_0^1 \sum_{i=0}^{n-y} {n-y\choose i}(-1)^ix^{i+y}~dx \\
&= {n\choose y}\sum_{i=0}^{n-y}{n-y\choose i}(-1)^i\frac{x^{i+y+1}}{i+y+1}\bigg|_0^1 \\
&= {n\choose y}\sum_{i=0}^{n-y}\frac{{n-y\choose i}(-1)^i}{i+y+1}
\end{align*}

Comment: wow nice....much appreciated -- i learned something new here!

Comment: That also simplifies to $ \dfrac{1}{n+1}$

Answer (score 2):

I just realized that the integral is an archetype of a beta distribution and thus can be manipulated as such...[beta distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution)

$\int_{0}^{1}\begin{pmatrix}n\\y\end{pmatrix}x^y(1-x)^{n-y}\,dx$ ~ $\frac {\Gamma(\alpha+\beta)}{\Gamma(\alpha)\Gamma(\beta)}x^{\alpha-1}(1-x)^{\beta-1} $$\Rightarrow$ which integrates to 1 over the support (0,1).

Thus, if $\alpha-1=y$ and $\beta-1=n-y$ $\implies$ $\begin{pmatrix}n\\y\end{pmatrix}$$\frac{\Gamma(y+1)\Gamma(n-y+1)}{\Gamma(n+2)} $

I'm sloppy so hope I didn't make an algebra mistake. It should (I hope!) come out to the same thing  @josliber wrote, and he still gets the credit because he managed more creativity IMO.

Comment: $\displaystyle {n \choose y}\frac{\Gamma(y+1)\Gamma(n-y+1)}{\Gamma(n+2)}$ can be simplified to $\dfrac{1}{n+1}$ for integers